# Preserving random numbers generated during app execution until the app exits in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a function code to generate random numbers.

```
func randomNumGenerate() -> Int {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HHmmss"

        let currentTimeStr = formatter.string(from: Date())

        return Int(currentTimeStr) ?? 0
    }
```

Then use this number to run another class function.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        BookAPI.requestGenre(bookGenre: 13, bookAddPoint: bookAddPoint, randomSeed: randomNumGenerate(), completionHandler: handleBooksGenre(books:error:))

    }
```

When the class function is executed, the data of `bookGenre: 13` is randomly sorted because of the `randomNumGenerate()` number generated.

But the problem is that when I go to another viewController and then back to the viewController with the above function again, the numbers are randomly generated and the alignment changes.

How can I keep the random numbers generated when the app runs until the app exits?

Comment: This random number is not so random. It will repeat every day and every second.

Comment: Can't I keep the currentTimeStr generated when the app runs?

Comment: You create a property for it in your view controller class that you assign the value to. `var randomBookGenre: Int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate the random number as soon as the app launches, in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
// AppDelegate.swift
var randomNumber: Int!
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    randomNumber = randomNumGenerate()
    return true
}
```

This ensures that only one random number is generated per launch.

And then in your VC, access this random number:

```
let randomNumber = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).randomNumber
BookAPI.requestGenre(
    bookGenre: 13, 
    bookAddPoint: bookAddPoint, 
    randomSeed: randomNumber, 
    completionHandler: handleBooksGenre(books:error:))
```